# What font package do I use to get the vertical Russian/German style integral signs?

Tags: fonts, symbols

What font package do I use to get the vertical Russian/German style integral signs? (subject says all)

Comment: For those who don't know the said variants, Wikipedia shows the symbols in an image file: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_symbol

Comment: I have recently graduated from a Russian university.  I never seen a "Russian" integral; instead, the integral symbol used here in books and handwritings is "German".  I've just checked a couple of Russian math books published in 80's, and they use German variant too.  So, perhaps, German style would be enough for you.

Comment: Similar questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170028/integral-sign-int and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222243/how-to-obtain-a-bold-upright-integral-sign

Answer (score 13):

The German one can be produced with the `wasysym` package. More precisely, if loaded without arguments, then the package provides a `\varint` command for the upright integral. If loaded with the `integrals` option, it overrides the normal `\int` command.

The integrals from `mathabx` (it redefines `\int`) are beckwards slanted when used in inline style and upright when in display style.

(Generally if you look for a symbol, [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) and the [comprehensive symbol list](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/) are of invaluable help.)

Comment: Now why didn't detexify find those when I looked!

Comment: Maybe they are not (yet) in the list of symbols detexify knows about.

Answer (score 1):

According to [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), the German one (upright, according to Wikipedia) is in the font package [tipa](http://ctan.uib.no/fonts/tipa) as the command `\textesh`, but there it's regarded as a phonetic symbol so is a *text* character.  That means that it won't behave correctly *as is* in mathematics: that is, it won't stretch and it won't have the limits in the right place.  However, it could (probably) be converted to one.

The closest detexify gives for the Russian one is `\rbag` in the [stmaryrd](https://ctan.org/pkg/stmaryrd?lang=en) package, but it looks a little odd at the bottom.