# where to find font including an extensible version of a straight integral?

Tags: fonts, symbols

Where can I find the integral shown in page 17 of [*Russian Typographical Traditions in Mathematical Literature*](http://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://www.uni-giessen.de/partosch/eurotex99/zaitsev.pdf&ei=EDeYTeG3OMzIcfL1gLEH&usg=AFQjCNHb8WyFz9sEPMKDuLdwC0yQGfYDkA) ?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Comment: Related: [What font package do I use to get the vertical Russan/German style integral signs?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/971/1235)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about that particular integral sign, but the Euler math fonts have an upright integral sign and the STIX fonts have variants for its integrals which are upright also.

Comment: @W.R.: wiki link (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_symbol)

Comment: @lyashenko You want the german symbol or the russian symbol ?  In the texte, I read that German-style integrals are also sometimes seen in Russian literature.

Comment: @Iyashenko Ah, I see; sorry for the misunderstanding. I hope that someone creates a nice OpenType Russian-style maths font!

Answer (score 2):

This one ??

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{mathabx}  

\begin{document}
    $\int$
    \[\int\]
\end{document}
```

[image: inline math]
[image: displaymath]

Comment: You can search inside `symbols-a4.pdf`   `http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/`

Comment: The large symbol is incorrect.

Comment: @lyashenko With mathabx  inline and display math symbols are different ! (why ? I don't know) but I don't understand what you want : something like the inline symbol ? because page 17 of your link, and in wikipedia, the russian symbol for integral seems to be a slanted symbol. It's not very easy to found !

Comment: @Miriam.Yeung : a correct large one is probably difficult to make, since the (invert) slope of the central region would depend on its vertical height.