# Integral Sign $\int...$

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

does anybody know how to write integral signs in LaTex that are slanted to the left, and not the right. See here if you do not know what I mean:

[image]

(From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Integral_Uprightness.svg)

This is how it is written in Bulgaria and Russia and many other places so I am curious.  Thank you.

My problem is that the integral sign now is

```
$$
\int ...
$$
```

and is leaning to the right, not the left like shown in the picture I attached.  I want to know how to write it so that it is slanted to the left.  Thank you

Comment: Wow. Russians really do have a slanted view of things.

Comment: @DavidH a slanted view but can integrate all functions!!

Comment: My comment seems to have been lost in the migration. You may find [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/971/what-font-package-do-i-use-to-get-the-vertical-russan-german-style-integral-sign) from tex.stackexchange helpful. Also found [this](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=23928) with a little more detail.

Comment: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=23928

Comment: the stix fonts have both styles of integrals.  i'm not sure how to switch them though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This answer follows the additional Russian typographic tradition (Figure 5 of http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/eurotex99/zaitsev.pdf) of having the limits above and below the integral sign in `\displaystyle`.  The `\rint` is essentially an `\int` (of the current math style) with a 15 degree rotation applied to it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\rint}{\ThisStyle{\rotatebox{15}{$\SavedStyle\!\int\!$}}}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
\[ 
f=\int_0^t A d\tau =\rint_0^t A d\tau
\]
\centering
\(
f=\int_0^t A d\tau =\rint_0^t A d\tau
\)\par
\(
\scriptstyle f=\int A d\tau =\rint A d\tau
\)\par
\(
\scriptscriptstyle f=\int A d\tau =\rint A d\tau
\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

And here is a slight variation on the above solution in which a 30% horizontal stretch is applied to the integral sign, in an attempt to provide a width that is more in line with the literature.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\rint}{\ThisStyle{\hstretch{1.3}{\rotatebox{18}{$\SavedStyle\!\int\!$}}}}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
\[ 
f=\int_0^t A d\tau =\rint_0^t A d\tau
\]
\centering
\(
f=\int_0^t A d\tau =\rint_0^t A d\tau
\)\par
\(
\scriptstyle f=\int A d\tau =\rint A d\tau
\)\par
\(
\scriptscriptstyle f=\int A d\tau =\rint A d\tau
\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

And here is a final variation of the 1st solution in which the `\rint` sign is always a scaled version of the `\textstyle\rint`, the net effect being to make a particularly wider symbol in `\displaystyle` than either of the two other approaches.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\rint}{\scalerel*{\rotatebox{17}{$\!\int\!$}}{\int}}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
\[ 
f=\int_0^t A d\tau =\rint_0^t A d\tau
\]
\centering
\(
f=\int_0^t A d\tau =\rint_0^t A d\tau
\)\par
\(
\scriptstyle f=\int A d\tau =\rint A d\tau
\)\par
\(
\scriptscriptstyle f=\int A d\tau =\rint A d\tau
\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful except I cannot get the codes to run.  How come when I try to run these codes, I get errors?  "File `scalerel.sty' not found. \usepackage"

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That package is quite new; you could probably get it by updating your TeX installation. Alternatively, you can [download it from ctan](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/scalerel).

Comment: @Jeff As Ian says, the package can be downloaded.  You can place `scalerel.sty` in your working directory until such time as you figure out how to install the package permanently.

Comment: @IanThompson Thank you.  I will download it now.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks to you too!  I will let you know when I get it all working properly!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes & Ian:  Thanks, it is all working now!  Steven, this code is very helpful to me thanks for all the detail and examples you have provided