# Compress integral symbol \int horizontally

Tags: graphics, symbols, integral

As the title suggests, is there a way to adjust the width of the integral symbol by compressing it in the horizontal direction? Adjustbox only seems to allow me to adjust the height, and the width does not change.

Comment: Member of over one year, 22 posts and no [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? -1

Comment: Are you trying to save space or make it look different? A little negative space before and after to givene things up might work better if it's just a space issue

Answer (score 3):

Use `\resizebox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\int$
\resizebox{.5\width}{\height}{$\displaystyle\int$}
$\displaystyle\int$
\end{document}
```

[image]

or use an upright integral symbol which is naturally narrower, e.g. from `eulervm`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareSymbolFont{eulargesymbols}{U}{zeuex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{eulargesymbols}{"52}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\int$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for your alternative solution. The change in the weight of the (near) vertical stroke in the first option doesn't look nice.

Answer (score 1):

Here I use `scalerel` package's `\hstretch` to compress the sign to 80, 60, and 40%, respectively.  Unlike `\resizebox`, it automatically works across math styles.  I have embodied it here as `\varint[<scale>]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\varint[1][.8]{\mathrel{\hstretch{#1}{\int}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\int_0^x \varint_{\!\!\!0}^x \varint[.6]_{\!\!0}^x  \varint[.4]_{\!0}^x 
\]
\[
\scriptstyle \int \varint \varint[.6] \varint[.4]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

See this related question, [Integral Sign $\int...$](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170028/integral-sign-int), for integral signs that are naturally more vertical and less slanted; in the Russian style, as it were.